# For a TChart Series, how do you keep the Gradient within the X-Y Axis?

Tags: delphi, c++builder, teechart

I am working on creating a risk matrix where the gradient needs to represent risk. I have used the TChart editor to set colors (green, yellow, red) and direction ("Diagonal Up") for the gradient color. It all looks good except that the gradient goes to the edge of the TChart Panel rather than being cropped at the X, and Y axis. This makes the most intense colors outside of the data.

Is there a way to make the gradient stay within X & Y?

Thanks.

[Sample Showing gradient outside of grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehBba.png)

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify your question by including two images, one showing the current appearance and one showing the desired appearance (which you can probably make in Microsoft Paint)?

Comment: That sounds like you've set the gradient color for an incorrect chart component...

Comment: I added an image that illustrates the issue.